# Showing a set of all continuous functions $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ is uncountable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be a set of all continuous functions $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$. I wish to show that $A$ is uncountable.

Note that a set $X$ is uncountable means $X$ is infinite and there is no bijection $f:\mathbb N \to X$. (if such bijection $f:\mathbb N \to X$ exists, then $X$ is countable.)

My attempt at proof:

Let $B\subseteq A$ be a set of all constant functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$. It suffices to show that $B$ is uncountable. The number of constant function is limited by $\mathbb R$, i.e. $|B|=|\mathbb R|$. Since $\mathbb R$ is uncountable, $B$ is also uncountable. Hence, $A$ is uncountable.

Here I am using the fact that all countable sets has a finite or countable subset and $\mathbb R$ is uncountable. I am not sure if my proof looks alright because I don't know how to justify that $|B|=|\mathbb R|$. Let me know if there are other issues I overlooked.

Comment: This is fine. constant functions are in clear bijection with real numbers (map a constant function to the value of its constant)

Comment: Your last paragraph should read, "Here I am using the fact that *every* subset of a countable set must be finite or countable, so demonstrating the existence of an uncountable subset proves that the set can't be countable."  You have the concept correct -- it's the write-up that slightly misses the mark.